# Hyperledger fabric:got unexpected status: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet:

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am new for hyper ledger fabric.I am following fabric docs to establish the first network. but for below command, I am getting an error, mentioned below. Please help.

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile 
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

> Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update:
>   error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application
>   not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies,
>   required 1 remaining

I am using fabric :1.1

docker : 17.06.2-ce
window :10

Comment: How are you managing the crypto materials and channel artifacts?Are you following the official documentation give here>http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

Comment: Thanks, Nilakantha,  issue resolved .there was a problem in binary which I downloaded using fabric docs. Now I took these binaries one of my colleagues and all working now.